# Why is a sort function in the global namespace?

Tags: c++, std

Why is there a sort function in the global namespace in C++? Why this code compiles?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> array(10);
    sort(array.begin(), array.end());
}
```

PS: clang++ --std=c++11 --stdlib=libc++ ./test.cpp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sort` isn't in the global namespace, it's in `std`. However, the result type of `vector::begin()` *may* be in `std` too (this is implementation-dependent). If so then `std::sort` is found by ADL (argument-dependent lookup).

If you don't want `std::sort` to be found by ADL then you can make a qualified call to `sort` instead of an unqualified one: `::sort(array.begin(), array.end())`.

Comment: So what should i do if i want to implement my sort function which takes same arguments?

Comment: BTW:  This seems to be a good description of ADL:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: http://codepad.org/lhD0Llmy i want to add this code. And ask the same question because it output sorted array. So used std::sort. Clang++ only.

Comment: @SukhanovNiсkolay if your sort is in the global namespace, you can call it with `::sort(args);`. But I suggest you put it in your own namespace.

Comment: @juanchopanza ok, but i think it is strange isn't it? Because as i understood ADL only works if there isn't my own implementation of this function in namespace?

Comment: @SukhanovNiсkolay No, ADL works because the arguments (A) are in the `std` namespace.

Comment: And one more question i haven't included algorithm library? why this works without it?

Comment: @SukhanovNiсkolay Good point. It must be brought in by either of your two includes. Of course, you can't rely on that, it is a feature of this implementation.

Comment: Weird that the standard `vector` iterators aren't just naked pointers.

Comment: @kerreksb not really.  esp in debug, adding checks for UB is worth it.  And in release, slightly less than naked pointers gives you a more consistent compile result to debug.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It would be very irresponsible to have the iterators be classes in debug mode and pointers in release mode, since then they would interact differently with overload resolution, ADL, etc. Which is enough of a reason on its own to have them always be non-pointer classes in `std::`. I would think/hope that a good compiler will optimise the class iterators away anyway, though I don't remember testing this, but that's because I trust my compiler!